# How to access geo ip look up with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like ot know how I can consume the output of this service with JavaScript.

It's not valid JSON

http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org/

**EDIT**
Here is how I was hoping to retrieve the data:

```
$.ajax('http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org/', {
    crossDomain:true,
    success:function(data,text,xhqr){
        alert(data);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it's response contains a string which can be easily processed with simple JS. Try this.

```
var geoStr = 'Geo = {"city":"Woodbury","country":"US","lat":"39.824001","lon":"-75.131798","IP":"98.110.51.114","netmask":"24"};';

var geoJSON = geoStr.split('=')[1];

geoJSON = $.parseJSON(geoJSON.substring(0, geoJSON.length -1));

console.log(geoJSON);
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rWhUj/)**

Comment: This is helpful but I guess my question wasn't clear. I would like to know how I can access the output of that service via ajax.

Comment: @Terra - Since it is in different domain you cannot access it from your website. You might have to retrieve it from server side.

Comment: For Cross domain access you take a look at this http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

Comment: I think that's already being taken into an account by jQuery's crossDomain:true ajax method.

Comment: No, it is not taken care by default.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and AJAX will do the trick. Like ShankarSangoli said, this will work cross-domain.
Here is an working example:

```
 var query = "select * from html where url='http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org'"
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query.toLowerCase()),
            url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodedQuery + '&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?';
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

                var w = data.query.results.body.p;
                var geoJSON = w.split('=')[1];
                geoJSON = $.parseJSON(geoJSON);

                var latitude = geoJSON.lat;
                var longitude = geoJSON.lon;


                console.log('Geo IP: ('+ latitude + ' - ' + longitude +')');

            }
        });
```

You can also try these links if you are working on a HTML5 Geolocation Fallback method:
http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp
http://freegeoip.net/json/