# detect place using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to detect that from which country and form which timezone my website is opened by user using java script or Jquery

Comment: Also this other [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489460/how-to-get-visitors-location-i-e-country-using-javascript-geolocation)

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6939685/1810429).

Comment: Possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867369/how-to-access-geo-ip-look-up-with-javascript

Comment: A [simple web search](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=detect+requester+location+and+timezone+with+javascript) immediately returns what seem to be usable possibilities, some of them on SO as the "possible duplicate" comments indicate: if your situation is subtly different, please explain.  Regardless, try to explain what you have tried, what is not working or does not suit your specific needs etc.

Answer (score 2):

Timezone is possible to get with Javascript alone, country is not possible without a third-party service or server-side process like `GeoIP`:

`var timezone = new Date().toString().match(/\(([A-Z]+)\)$/).pop()`